# URL rewriting breaks when index.php?url=index (parameter is "index"). Why?

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Weird issue: I'm using this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

to get these URLs. Works perfectly.

```
http://www.example.com/cool/url
```

### Problem

But when the *?url*-parameter has the word index in it, like in

```
http://www.example.com/index/page
```

then $_GET["url"] is empty. I think my RewriteRule is broken (despite i've seen exactly this RewriteRule in lots of tutorials) and the removing of index.php from the URL also removes the index-parameter.

### Question

How to fix, how to make URLs like index/page possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to [`MultiViews option`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html).

Add this line on top of your `.htaccess` file to disable `MultiViews`:

```
Options -MultiViews
```